# What's the key sequence to run a function by typing the function name in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Suppose I add a new word count function to my .emacs file to count words:

(defun word-count nil "Count words in buffer" (interactive)
(shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "wc -w"))

I remember there being a way to run a function by typing the function name, but I don't remember how.  What key sequence do I type before I type word-count, enter?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  It's M-x.  That's what I assumed it was, but it didn't work the first time because emacs doesn't recognize a new function in .emacs until you restart emacs.

Comment: In addition to restarting, you can also use M-x load-file to reread .emacs, or use M-x eval-region to evaluate an arbitrary piece of elisp (in this case your defun).

Comment: You can accomplish the same by `M-x load-file` and then ` ~/.emacs` (or whatever the path to your .emacs is)

Comment: And another alternative: place point (the cursor) at the closing paren for the new function and hit `C-x C-e` or run `eval-last-sexp`.